# Schedule shutdown for mac

Tags: macos, shell, cron, shutdown

I'm trying to automate the shutdown of my mac, I have written a script to shutdown the mac.I have included the code to display dialogue box which displays message that "Your computer will shutdown after 30 seconds" and counter goes down till 0 seconds. But somehow it is not working. 
Steps I followed:

Here is how to create a sleep cronjob for MAC.

Step 1: open a terminal

Step 2: copy folder to desktop

Step 3: cd ~/Desktop/cronjob_to_sleep/

Step 4: sudo ./makeShutDownScript.sh

Step 5: sudo crontab -e

```
    5.1 An editor will open 
    5.2 Press i
    5.3 copy this line (you can add more): 59 23 * * 1 /shutdown.sh
    5.4 Hit backspace if extra space (delete in mac keybaord)
    5.5 Press ESC
    5.6 press :
    5.7 press w
    5.8 press q
    5.9 Hit enter
```

Step 6: You are done.

Step 7: Verify using sudo crontab -l

*makeShutDownScript.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh


# Step 1 -> Create shutdown.sh at /
echo "#!/bin/sh
#This script shutsdown the system

time=30
c = 1

while [ \$time -gt 0 ]

do

clear
if [ \$c -eq 1 ]
then
    echo \"#### Message from Admin ####\"
    echo \"This system will shutdown in \$time seconds, press CTRL+C to cancel\"
    c=0
else
    echo \"**** Message from Admin ****\"
    echo \"This system will shutdown in \$time seconds, press CTRL+C to cancel\"
    c=1
fi
time=\`expr \$time - 1\`
sleep 1
done

/sbin/shutdown -h now

" > /shutdown.sh

# Step 2 -> Permissions

chmod 777 /shutdown.sh
```

Comment: why are you recreating `shutdown.sh` each day? Why not just have that be the cmd in `cron` entry? `echo " ..... multiline string ..." > file` is an invitation to trouble ;-) Good luck.

Comment: I tried that too. My problem is it is not showing the dialogue box before it shutdowns. Any idea about that?